# How to use Highcharts getSelectedPoints to get comma separated string of selected pie slices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, highcharts

I am adapting the Highcharts Pie Chart Demo so that immediately after clicking a pie slice (either `MouseClick` for exclusive selection or `Shift-MouseClick` for multiple selection), a separate span element shows a comma-separated string of the names of the selected pie slices.

The span element successfully shows the value of the clicked pie slice when `MouseClick` happens. However, when doing `Shift-MouseClick` to select multiple slices, the span only shows the most-recently-selected pie slice rather than the set of selections.

```
events: {
    select: function () {
    $("#chosenProgram").text(this.options.name);
    }
}
```

I have found many forum answers suggesting the use of `getSelectedPoints()`, but the examples, such as found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/joelion/QJ75h/), appear to be done in the context of line charts and not pie charts. I tried the code in those examples anyway at best got '', '[object Object]', or '[object Object],[object Object]' as a response.

```
events: {
    select: function () {
        // -- Attempt to get multiple-select to work
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var selectedPointsStr = "";                                    
        var selectedPoints = chart.getSelectedPoints();
        $.each(selectedPoints, function (i, value) {
            selectedPointsStr += "<br>" + value.category;
        });

        // I'm not getting the name of the seelcted pie slices
        // AND, it seems to be "before-click" instead of "after-click"
        alert(selectedPoints);
    }
}
```

What I would like to see is -- as an example: "Option A" or "Option A, Option C" as a result of slice selection, or the default "Unfiltered" if no options are chosen.  How can this be done with a pie chart?

For reference here is current HTML I am working on.  Look for `series > point > events` to see the relevant code. (On another note, is there a way to highlight a relevant part of the code block?).

```
<h2>Modular View</h2>

<div id="selectedInfo">
    <h3>Selected Program type: <span id="chosenProgram" style="text-decoration:underline">Unfiltered</span></h3>
</div>

<h3>Instructions:</h3>
<ul>
    <li><code>MouseClick</code> to exclusively select only one slice.</li>
    <li><code>Shift+MouseClick</code> to select or deselect multiple slices.</li>
</ul>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; border:thin solid black"></div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="~/Scripts/HighCharts/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                var chartName = 'Program Type';
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false,
                        type: 'pie'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: chartName
                    },
                    tooltip: { enabled: false },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>',
                                style: {
                                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: chartName,
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                select: function () {
                                    // This works for single-slice selection
                                    //var chart = $("#container").highcharts();                                    
                                    //$("#chosenProgram").text(this.options.name);

                                    // -- Attempt to get multiple-select to work
                                    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                                    var selectedPointsStr = "";                                    
                                    var selectedPoints = chart.getSelectedPoints();
                                    $.each(selectedPoints, function (i, value) {
                                        selectedPointsStr += "<br>" + value.category;
                                    });

                                    // I'm not getting the name of the seelcted pie slices
                                    // AND, it seems to be "before-click" instead of "after-click"
                                    alert(selectedPoints);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        data: [{ name: 'Option A', y: 33 },
                            { name: 'Option B', y: 33 },
                            { name: 'Option C', y: 33 }]
                    }]
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have been able to gather, I can use a button click (or link click) separate from the Highcharts function itself to read what is selected.

So, if the customer can accept reading pie selections with a separate button, this is an answer.

If your client, like mine, says, "That's great, but can't you do it without the button? [i.e., multiple selections]" This is not yet an answer. I have not yet seen any working examples where this is successful.

There is one important subtlety to keep in mind when focusing on "update the selection summary while I click" behavior. Some users like to play around with the selections (click random slices, select and de-select slices, etc.) as if they were trying to be beta testers. I have not yet seen any existing code samples correctly keep the selection summary in sync with what the users are actually clicking. While some people might respond, "You need to train your users better," my counter-response is that I have no control over my users, but I can control what I deliver so I don't get false bug reports back from the user.

The one benefit of the code below is that the users can do whatever they want: when they click the button, the code will read what is selected at the time the button is clicked.

```
<h2>Modular View</h2>

<div id="selectedInfo">
    <h3>Selected Program type: <span id="chosenProgram" style="text-decoration:underline">Unfiltered</span></h3>
</div>

<h3>Instructions:</h3>
<ul>
    <li><code>MouseClick</code> to exclusively select only one slice.</li>
    <li><code>Shift+MouseClick</code> to select or deselect multiple slices.</li>
</ul>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; border:thin solid black"></div>

<p><button id="ReadSelections">Read Selections</button></p>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="~/Scripts/HighCharts/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Read selected pie slices in chart(s)
            $("#ReadSelections").click(function () {
                var x = "";
                var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                var selectedPoints = chart.getSelectedPoints();
                var i = 0;
                $.each(selectedPoints, function (i, value) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        x = value.name;
                    }
                    else {
                        x += ", "+value.name;
                    }
                    i++;
                });

                    if(x!=="")
                        $("#chosenProgram").text(x);
                else
                        $("#chosenProgram").text("None selected");
            });

            // Generate Pie Chart
            $(function () {
                var chartName = 'Program Type';
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false,
                        type: 'pie'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: chartName
                    },
                    tooltip: { enabled: false },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>',
                                style: {
                                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: chartName,
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        data: [{ name: 'Option A', y: 33 },
                            { name: 'Option B', y: 33 },
                            { name: 'Option C', y: 33 }]
                    }]
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: For me it works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/QJ75h/20/ Just note: `getSelectedPoints()` returns list of already selected points, it won't include current point, so you need to add this (`this.name`).

Comment: I looked at the link. Is modification of code required? As written, I'm not seeing the intended behavior as shown in my code immediately above.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite following you. Open my jsfiddle demo - it works as you requested in the question. Of course there is `Slice` only, but this is caused by missing `name` for points in my demo.

Comment: I should see the string summary match whatever is selelected. If slices are  de-selected, the string summary should match that. Try de-selecting slices, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Ah, I see. It happens, because `select` is not called when **deselecting** points. Instead use `click` event. There you can compare selected points with current point and check the `selected` status. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QJ75h/21/